# Function "PropertyExists" in GeoServer style returns NullPointerException

Tags: geoserver, sld

I am using GeoServer 2.15.2.  With this as the "ogc:Filter" in my "FeatureTypeStyle" element ...

```
<ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
  <ogc:Function name="PropertyExists">
    <ogc:Literal>foo</ogc:Literal>
  </ogc:Function>
  <ogc:Literal>true</ogc:Literal>
</ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
```

... and GeoServer throws a NullPointerException (NPE):

2019-09-10 14:37:16,615 [http-apr-81-exec-9] ERROR - null [org.geotools.renderer.lite]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.geotools.filter.function.PropertyExistsFunction.evaluate(PropertyExistsFunction.java:94)
    at blah, blah, blah

The error occurs when attempting to view the layer via "Layer Preview" in the GeoServer web app.

Has anyone successfully used this function (lately) and if so can you provide a sample?

I tried a couple different spatial data sources, one being a layer in a GeoPackage and the other a ShapeFile just for kicks.  Both result in an NPE.

**Update - 2019-09-11:**

This is the extent of the stack trace while still in the "geotools" package.  The remaining 125 lines are outside of "geotools" in the geoserver, tomcat and spring packages (and I don't think that portion is helpful).

2019-09-10 14:37:16,615 [http-apr-81-exec-9] ERROR - null [org.geotools.renderer.lite]
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.geotools.filter.function.PropertyExistsFunction.evaluate(PropertyExistsFunction.java:94)
    at org.geotools.filter.visitor.SimplifyingFilterVisitor.visit(SimplifyingFilterVisitor.java:477)
    at org.geotools.filter.FunctionExpressionImpl.accept(FunctionExpressionImpl.java:143)
    at org.geotools.filter.visitor.DuplicatingFilterVisitor.visit(DuplicatingFilterVisitor.java:125)
    at org.geotools.filter.visitor.DuplicatingFilterVisitor.visit(DuplicatingFilterVisitor.java:170)
    at org.geotools.filter.visitor.SimplifyingFilterVisitor.visit(SimplifyingFilterVisitor.java:557)
    at org.geotools.filter.IsEqualsToImpl.accept(IsEqualsToImpl.java:154)
    at org.geotools.filter.visitor.SimplifyingFilterVisitor.collect(SimplifyingFilterVisitor.java:228)
    at org.geotools.filter.visitor.SimplifyingFilterVisitor.visit(SimplifyingFilterVisitor.java:160)
    at org.geotools.filter.AndImpl.accept(AndImpl.java:45)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.getStyleQuery(StreamingRenderer.java:1302)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.getFeatures(StreamingRenderer.java:2192)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.processStylers(StreamingRenderer.java:2156)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer.paint(StreamingRenderer.java:892)

Example feature the produces error:

```
wkt_geom    fid
LineString (-78.20535245444592931 38.73629880547370163, -78.20466261356823168 38.73735892913973089) 1
```

Full SLD that produces error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
 xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
 xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>test line</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Name>rule1</Name>
            <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:Function name="PropertyExists">
                  <ogc:Literal>foo</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:Function>
                <ogc:Literal>true</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:Filter>
            <LineSymbolizer>
              <Stroke>
                <CssParameter name="stroke">#0000FF</CssParameter>
              </Stroke>
            </LineSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: Your syntax looks similar than in this ticket https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-4928

Comment: My inspiration actually came from this thread:

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Referencing-the-feature-in-an-SLD-filter-Sec-Unclassified-td3794278.html

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [line 94 of `PropertyExistsFunction`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/library/main/src/main/java/org/geotools/filter/function/PropertyExistsFunction.java#L94) suggests that your feature is not simple and may well be null.

To be sure of what is happening we need to see the "blah, blah, blah" part of your log and an example feature.

Comment: I created a two feature, line string layer in a geopackage and was able to produce the the error.  I updated my original post, above, with an example of one of the two features.

Answer (score 0):

On GeoServer 2.18 my impression is that:

```
<ogc:Function name="PropertyExists">
    <ogc:Literal>foo</ogc:Literal>
</ogc:Function>
```

always returns false, but

```
<ogc:Function name="PropertyExists">
    <ogc:PropertyName>foo</ogc:PropertyName>
</ogc:Function>
```

will return true if it exists, unfortunately GeoServer returns:

```
<ServiceException>
The requested Style can not be used with this layer. The style specifies an attribute named 'foo', not found in the 'xxx:yyy' layer
</ServiceException>
```

if it doesn't exist.